# Suppose $f : X \to Y$ is a (continuous) bounded map.Does this implies that $f$ is uniformly continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, uniform-continuity

It's well known that if $ f : \bf (X,d) \to \bf (Y,e) $ is a uniformly continuous function then $f$  maps bounded set to bounded set.Does the converse hold ? More Precisely,

> Suppose $f : X \to Y$ is a (continuous) bounded map (i.e. $f$ maps bounded set to bounded set).Does this implies that $f$ is uniformly continuous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classic function $f:(0,1) \to [0,1]$
$$f(x) = \sin(1/x)$$
is a counterexample.

Comment: Dear @Crostul,Superb.Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is a well known lemma saying that if a function $f$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\int_0^{+\infty}f(x)dx$ converge and $f$ is uniformly continuous then $lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} f(x)dx = 0$.

Consider the function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=\sin(x^2)$. It satisfies your hypothesis and the integral of $f$ converges and its limit at $+\infty$ is not $0$ hence it's not uniformly continuous.

Comment: Dear @Hicham,Thank you! Perhaps easy way to show  that  $f$ is not unifomly continuous is to note that $f' \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty $.Could you please give me a reference for the lemma?

Comment: Dear Arpit, you're welcome. The derivative of the function in my example vanishes an infinite number of times near infinity, so it can't goes to infinity. And even if the derivative goes to infinity it is not obvious for me how we can prove the non-uniform continuity. I'll try to fin a counter example to this later. It is in general difficult to prove unirorm continuity on unbounded domains. That why I like this example, because it gives easily the non uniform continuity based on a general lemma.

Comment: For a reference check this link http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92105/f-uniformly-continuous-and-int-a-infty-fx-dx-converges-imply-lim-x

Comment: Thank you.Check this:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1571906/does-there-exist-a-f-bf-r-to-bf-r-which-is-differentiable-uniformly-contin

Comment: Thanks Arpit for the link.

Comment: Sorry, I am quite curious: I have never seen the fact that $\int_0^{\infty} \sin x^2 dx$ is convergent. Could you please give me alink for a proof of this fact?

Comment: It is known as Fresnel integral, we know even the value of this integral $$\int_0^{+\infty}\sin(x^2)dx = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{8}}$$. see the following link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral.

Comment: For a proof of convergence, we can use a variable change and an integration by part to write $$\int_0^{x}\sin(x^2)=\int_0^{x}\frac{\sin u }{2\sqrt u}du =[\frac{1-\cos u}{2\sqrt u}]_0^x+\int_0^{x}\frac{1-\cos u}{4u^{3/2}}du$$ from which you can see that all converge when $x$ goes to infinity