# Suppose $f$ is continuous and there is some $R >0$ such that $f(x) = 0$ whenever $|x|> R$. Prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, uniform-continuity

(a) Suppose that a function $f:R→R$ is continuous and “vanishes at infinity,” i.e., $lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}f(x) = 0 =  lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} f(x)$. Prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

(b) Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and there is some $R >0$ such that $f(x) = 0$ whenever $|x|> R$. Prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. (Hint: Even though the domain of $f$ is not a compact set, a theorem from class will be very helpful)

I know that a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is uniformly continuous if for any $\epsilon >0$, there exists a $\delta >0$ such that for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, \begin{equation*}
||x-y||<\delta \implies ||f(x)-f(y)||<\epsilon
\end{equation*}

I am not quite sure how to prove uniform continuity for these 2 parts given this definition. I am thinking the hint in part b refers to the theorem "if f is continuous and $K \subseteq R^n$ is compact, then f is uniformly continuous on the set K.

Comment: You are right about the hint for part b.

Comment: You are right about the hint for (b); consider the set $[-R,R]$. I would do (b) first and then combine it with the fact that a function that vanishes at infinity must have $|f(x)-f(y)|$ small when both $x$ and $y$ are large enough in absolute value.

Comment: The proof here can be adapted for a)  and b) is obvious from a): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1145847/f0-infty-rightarrow-mathbbr-is-continuous-prove-uniform-continuity-on?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For part b, the result result you mentioned is the way to go. It implies that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\{|x| \leq R\}$. Of course, since $f\equiv 0$ on $\{|x|>R\}$, it is uniformly continuous there as well. Could you figure out how to finish it from there?

For the first part, see this post: [A function vanishing at infinity is uniformly continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/705961/477460).
Once you prove part a, part b is just an immediate corollary. That would be an alternative to the above.