# Prove that $x^n e^{-x} $ is uniformly continuous on $[0, \infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, limits, continuity, uniform-continuity

Thus far I have shown that $|f(x)-f(y)| = e^{-x} |x^n - y^n e^{x-y}|$

Comment: Computing $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ may be useful.

Comment: In general, if a function $f$ is continuous in $[0,\infty)$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ exist and finite then $f$ is uniformly continuous in $[0,\infty)$. You can try to prove it and that will finish the exercise.

Comment: To elaborate on Mark's comment, note that if $f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\,f(x)=L$ for some finite real number $L$, then we can extend $f$ to the one-point compactification $[0,\infty]$ of $[0,\infty)$ via defining $\hat{f}:[0,\infty]\to\mathbb{R}$ to be $$\hat{f}(x):=\begin{cases}f(x)&\text{if }x\in[0,\infty)\,,\\ L&\text{if }x=\infty\,.\end{cases}$$  Now, $\hat{f}$ is a continuous function on the compact metric space $[0,\infty]$, which must be uniformly continuous according to [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110573).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function $f(x) = x^n e^{-x}$ is uniformly continuous on all compact intervals, as a continuous function, and tends to zero as $x \to \infty$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. It is therefore uniformly continuous by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-does-the-existence-of-a-limit-imply-that-a-function-is-uniformly-continuous).

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to prove that $f(x) = x^ne^{-x}$ is continuously differentiable and its derivative is bounded. Computing the first derivative you get
$$f'(x) = x^{n-1}(n-x)e^{-x}$$
which is continuous on $[0,+\infty)$. To find its maximum you can compute
\begin{align}
f''(x) & = (n-1)x^{n-2}(n-x)e^{-x}-x^{n-1}e^{-x}-x^{n-1}(n-x)e^{-x}\\
& = x^{n-2}e^{-x}((n-1)(n-x)-x-x(n-x)) \\
& = x^{n-2}e^{-x}(x^2-2nx+n^2-n).
\end{align}
This is positive when $0 < x < n-\sqrt{n}$ or $x > n+\sqrt{n}$. Since $f'$ tends to $0$ when $x \to +\infty$, it has a maximum at $x = n-\sqrt{n}$, where $f'(n-\sqrt{n}) = \sqrt{n}(n-\sqrt{n})^{n-1}e^{-n+\sqrt{n}} > 0$. Hence $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

$f_n$  is unifomly continuous at $[0,+\infty)$ since $f_n$ is continuous at $[0,+\infty)$ and $\lim_{x\to+\infty}=0\in \Bbb R$.
For a given $\epsilon>0,$
Use the fact that $f_n$ is uniformly continuous at some compact  $[0,a]$ wher $a$ is such that

$$x\ge a \text{ and } y\ge a \implies $$
$$|f(x)-f(y)|<|f(x)|+|f(y)|<\epsilon$$

to prove that $f_n$ is uniformly continuous at $[a,+\infty)$.

Now, we use the continuity of $f_n$ at the point $x=a$.

there exist some $\eta$ such that

$$x,y\in ]a-\eta,a+\eta[\implies $$
$$|f(x)-f(y)|\le |f(x)-f(a)|+|f(y)-f(a)|<\epsilon$$

You can take it.

Comment: I think the OP actually meant *uniformly continuous*.