# Is this function uniformly continuous or not?

Tags: real-analysis

I've been recently introduced to the concept of uniform continuity and I'm having some trouble deciding whether a function is uniformly continuous or not.
The function is: 
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\dfrac{\sin(x^5)}{x} & x\neq0 \\ 0 & x=0\end{cases}$$

I mean, I know that if the derivative of the function is bounded, then we can conclude that it is uniformly continuous, but if it isn't, I really don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Uniformly continuous *on what set*?

Comment: I believe it must be on $\mathbb R$

Comment: On all the real numbers

Comment: It can't be on $\mathbb{R}$: this function not defined at $x=0$.

Comment: 0 if x = 0, that expresion otherwise

Comment: Unfortunately, it's derivative isn't bounded, so we can't say that it's Lipschitz, and therefore uniformly continuous.

Comment: I've found a theorem that states: If a function $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R_+}$, and $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ exists, then that function is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R_+}$. So that function is indeed uniformly continuous.

Comment: [Here is a topic about that theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-does-the-existence-of-a-limit-imply-that-a-function-is-uniformly-continuous)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

Note that $\frac{\sin x^5}{x} = x^4 \frac{\sin x^5}{x^5} \to 0 \cdot 1 = 0$ as $x \to 0$ (from the left or the right).  Hence, $f$ is continuous and uniformly continuous on any compact interval $[-a,a]$.

Since $f(x) \to 0 $ as $|x| \to \infty$ the function is also uniformly continuous on intervals $(-\infty,-a]$ and $[a,\infty)$.   Any continuous function with a finite limit as $x \to \pm \infty$ is uniformly continuous -- proved many times on this site.

It is a common misconception that a function with a derivative that is unbounded for large $|x|$ cannot be uniformly continuous.  The condition that $|f'(x)| \to +\infty$ as $|x| \to +\infty$  guarantees non-uniform continuity.

Comment: Could you show me some proof of the fact that if $|f'(x)|\to \infty$ as $|x|\to \infty$ then it collides with uniform convergence?

Comment: @Jakobian: Sure. $|f(x) - f(y)| = |f'(\xi)||x - y|$ by the MVT.  For any $\delta > 0$ take $y = x + \delta/2$ so that $|x-y| < \delta$ and $|f(x) - f(y)| = |f'(\xi)|\delta/2$ Now this stays bigger than $1$ for some $x$ and $\xi > x$ sufficiently large if $|f'(x)| \to +\infty$.

Comment: @Jakobian Where did uniform **convergence** come into this question? I thought we were talking about continuity?

Comment: @RRL oh, thank you, it was a typo and it got me confused

Comment: @Jakobian It got me confused too, lol.

Comment: Yes, its about uniform continuity.