# If a multivariable continuous real function has $\lim_{\Vert x\Vert\to\infty} f(x) = L$, it is then uniformly continuous?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, uniform-continuity

An exercise sheet of my Multivariable Calculus subject asks you to prove that a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous if $\lim_{\Vert x\Vert\to\infty} f(x) = L$. I think I have nevertheless found a counterexample: taking $n=1$, the function $f(x)=\sin(1/x)$ for $x\neq 0$, $f(0)=0$ has limit 0 as x approaches both negative and positive infinity, but it is not uniformly continuous. Is my reasoning correct? Otherwise, can you give me some hints on how to deal with this proof? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your “counterexample” is not continuous at $x=0$.

Comment: Put the waves towards infinity and with frequency unbounded: $\sin(e^x)$.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy: Then how will $f$ have a limit at infinity? To deiv: Your title is very misleading — it's not just a question of boundedness.

Comment: @MartinR my mistake, you are indeed very correct. Then how can I tackle this problem? I think a proof by contradiction is the right path here, but I seem to be making little to no progress...

Comment: @TedShifrin Do you see me saying that it has limit at infinity?

Comment: Here is a proof: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2399462/42969.

Comment: @MartinR thanks!!