# uniform continuity of $f(x) = \frac{x}{1 +x^2}$ on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: limits, analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

$f(x) = \frac{x}{1 +x^2}$ on $\mathbb{R}$ to comment about its uniform continuity, I tried to figure out the definition "
A function $f(x)$ is said to be uniformly continuous on a set $S$, if for
given $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that
$x$, $y \in S$, $|x − y| < \delta ⇒ |f(x) − f(y)| < \epsilon$"  but couldn't get where to start.

then i thought about breaking down the interval into some closed and open intervals and as $f(x)$ is continuous in closed bounded interval so it would be uniformly continuous as well.  also i observed that limit $x$ tending to infinity and minus infinity exist and is equal to zero but don't know how to use it.

any hint would be highly appreciated

Comment: Any continuous function on $\mathbb R$ which has finite limits at $\pm \infty$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: Not as neat as geetha's solution, but you could also look to show that the derivative of $f$ is bounded. You can then use the mean value theorem to show that $\frac{|f(x) - f(y)|}{|x - y|}$ is bounded by the same constant, and uniform continuity follows readily from there.

Comment: See : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-does-the-existence-of-a-limit-imply-that-a-function-is-uniformly-continuous

Comment: @geetha290krm so similarly sinx/x can be solved as its limit at ±∞ exist and function is continuous on R

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is enough to prove that $f$ is Lipschitz continuous. By simple calculation,
$$
\left| {f(x) - f(y)} \right| = \frac{{\left| {xy - 1} \right|}}{{(x^2  + 1)(y^2  + 1)}}\left| {x - y} \right|.
$$
Observe that
$$
\left| {xy - 1} \right| \le |xy|+1=\sqrt {x^2 y^2 }  + 1 \le \frac{{x^2  + y^2 }}{2} + 1 = \frac{{(x^2  + 1) + (y^2  + 1)}}{2}.
$$
Whence
$$
\frac{{\left| {xy - 1} \right|}}{{(x^2  + 1)(y^2  + 1)}} \le \frac{{(x^2  + 1) + (y^2  + 1)}}{{2(x^2  + 1)(y^2  + 1)}} = \frac{1}{{2(y^2  + 1)}} + \frac{1}{{2(x^2  + 1)}} \le \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} = 1.
$$
Therefore, $|f(x)-f(y)|\le |x-y|$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb R$.

Comment: thanks, i got it now. although i am new to the topic, i find difficulty in having intuitive idea about any function's uniform continuity.

Answer (score 2):

Hint

By MVT,

$f(x)-f(y)=f^\prime(c)(x-y)$

with $|f^\prime(c)|=\bigg{|}\dfrac{1-c^2}{(1+c^2)^2} \bigg{|}\leq \ \dfrac{1+c^2}{(1+c^2)^2}\ \leq \dfrac{1}{(1+c^2)} \leq 1$

follows  $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq |x-y|$  for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Gary I think it is also correct. thank you . it is better.

Comment: yup, thanks for the hint, i guess i would be able to solve it now